# What is ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem preferLocal for?

Tags: c#, .net-core, threadpool

I've just noticed that .NET core introduces an overload of Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem  which takes a boolean called 'preferlocal' and allows me to pass through a type-safe state object (it has a generic parameter)

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netcore-2.1#System_Threading_ThreadPool_QueueUserWorkItem__1_System_Action___0____0_System_Boolean_) is currently incomplete and looks like this (for posterity - it may be updated in the future):

```
QueueUserWorkItem<TState>(Action<TState>, TState, Boolean)
C#

public static bool QueueUserWorkItem<TState> (Action<TState> callBack, TState state, bool preferLocal);

Type Parameters TState

Parameters
callBack Action<TState>

state

preferLocal Boolean

Returns
Boolean
```

What is this boolean (preferLocal) for and how will it affect my code?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12442

Comment: Raised a [doc issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8258). Just in case anyone wants to remind the people involved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like it was added by [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/14214) which links to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12442) (both Github links, "Add ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(..., bool preferLocal)/#14214" and "Add QueueUserWorkItem for local threadpool queues/#12442", respectively).

The issue is described as:

> ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem always queues to the global queue;
>   however it would be good to have the option to be able to queue to the
>   current threadpool thread's local queue when a threadpool thread
>   queues extra work items.
>
> **Rationale and Usage**
>
> - Reduced contention on the global queue when many threads are queuing
> - Potentially hotter more local data when the queuing work item completes
> - Take advantage of threadpool's task stealing
> - (i.e. Similar to Task's rational for doing it for child Tasks)

For me, it feels a pity that up to date in-line documentation (from which the MSDN documentation is generated) isn't a pre-requisite for pull requests.

---

When the Thread Pool was first built, it only had a single queue of work to be done. However, when all of the `Task` goodness was being plumbed into the framework, they took the opportunity to introduce thread-local queues (and [work stealing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jennifer/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0/)) alongside what was now renamed the global queue. It looks like this is clean-up work to allow specific access to these queues.

Comment: Ping them or add an issue? Those guys are quite prolific on Twitter

Comment: Thanks Damien, That is a really clear, concise answer and has helped me understand.

Comment: @Jay - it turned into a bit of a chase, first confirming it wasn't in .NET Standard, then that it was mentioned in neither "What's New in .NET Core 2.1" nor "What's New in .NET Core 2.0" which then mean searching github would be the only way to find anything more about it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever does it indirectly help GC with cleaning up the TState instance when we pass a reference there?

Comment: @Ugur - so far as I'm aware, GC is completely irrelevant here.